# Updating Sales Order line items in Dynamics business central

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-nav, dynamics-business-central

I have a sales order created using API for business central. Sales order has a single line item. I want to update the quantity of line item. Following is what I have tried so far.

Endpoint: `https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v1.0/domain.com/api/v1.0/companies(company_id)/salesOrders(sales_order_ide)/salesOrderLines(sales_order_line_id)`

where sales order line id is of the form `e86d3aa1-f2f8-ea11-aa61-0022481e3b8c-10000`
as described in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/api-reference/v1.0/api/dynamics_salesorderline_update#http-request) When a `PATCH` request is made, I get the following exception:

> ')' or ',' expected at position 9 in
> '(sale-order-line-item-id)'.

The exception stated above was also occuring when i was simply trying to get the line item but that was fixed when I changed the URL and it took the form:

Endpoint:

```
https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v1.0/domain.com/api/v1.0/companies(b4a4beb2-2d42-40dc-9229-5b5c371be4e3)/salesOrders(e86d3aa1-f2f8-ea11-aa61-0022481e3b8c)/salesOrderLines?filter=sequence eq 10000
```

This endpoint is returning correct response when i try to get the line item by issuing
`GET` request. However, when I issue a `PATCH` request using the same endpoint, with a simple request body e.g.

```
{"quantity" : 2.0}
```

it throws the exception:

> 'PATCH' requests for 'salesOrderLines' of EdmType 'Collection' are not
> allowed within Dynamics 365 Business Central OData web services.

I am also specifying the `if-Match` header along with the request that contains etag value for the line item but of no avail and same exception is occurring. Am I missing something? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For those who may visit this question later, after much hit and trial through Postman, I finally figured out the problem. In my case `if-Match` header that's basically is  `Etag` for the line item is all fine. The Problem was with API URL, specifically the way we specify the line item id. We have to specify this in single quotes so the URL for API call becomes:
[https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v1.0/domain.com/api/v1.0/companies(company_id)/salesOrders(sales_order_ide)/salesOrderLines('sales_order_line_id')](https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v1.0/domain.com/api/v1.0/companies(company_id)/salesOrders(sales_order_ide)/salesOrderLines(%27sales_order_line_id%27))

You would note that we are not specifying `company_id` and `sales_order_id` in single quotes, reason being, both of these parameters a of type `GUID` whereas `sales_order_line_id` is of type `string` as per metadata document.